# Can anyone explain to me why the following code throws System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException?

Tags: .net, reflection

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace A
{
  interface IObjectWithId<TId>
  {
    TId Id { get; }
  }
  interface IEntityBase : IObjectWithId<object>
  {
    new object Id { get; }
  }
  abstract class BusinessObject<TId> : IObjectWithId<TId>
  {
    public abstract TId Id { get; }
  }
  class EntityBase : BusinessObject<object>, IEntityBase
  {
    public override object Id { get { return null; } }
  }

  public static class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(typeof(EntityBase).GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled
  Message="Ambiguous match found."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
       at System.Type.GetProperty(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
       at A.Program.Main() in C:\Home\work\A\Program.cs:line 26
  InnerException:
```

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
>   Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
>   Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 3.5 SP1

**EDIT:**

Strangely enough, looks like other folks fail to reproduce it. Though it does crash on my machine every time. I found out that this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(EntityBase).GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, typeof(object), Type.EmptyTypes, null));
```

Does work OK, although it should be the same.

Comment: Aren't there any exception details providing more information ?

Comment: I just ran this code in VS2008/.net 3.5 and I didn't get an exception. What version of .net are you using?

Comment: No exception for me as well. VS2008/.Net 3.5

Comment: I am not inventing this, folks. It really happens to me.

Comment: I removed About info as it is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get your question answered, I'll get you familiar with the term 'Method Table'. This is part of the internal representation of types in the .NET framework, where every .NET type has its own method table. You can imagine it as a hash map (or a dictionary) containing all the methods and properties of the type. The key is the method/property signature (method name and parameter types, without the return type) and the value is a collection of matching methods/properties, alongside some reflection metadata information such as which type has declared the method/property.

When class `A` derives from a base class - `B`, or implements an interface `C`, the items in the method table of `B` and `C` become directly available in the method table of `A`. If the method table of `A` already contains an item with certain signature, that item is added to the collection for the same signature, so now `A` will have 2 methods/properties that the signature points to. The only way to distinguish these duplicate entries is by comparing the metadata describing the type on which behalf the signature is declared.

Lets take the interface `IObjectWithId<TId>`, which defines a property `TId ID { get; set; }`. The `EntityBase` class implements `IObjectWithId<TId>` so receives an `TId ID { get; set; }` property to its method table. At the same time this class implements the `IEntityBase` interface, which gives it the `Object ID { get; set; }` property. The `EntityBase` class then receives two properties under the same signature (because the return type does not participate in the signature), while it will still expose 2 different properties. The following declaration will result in a compile error:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<int>
   {
        public int ID { get; set; }
   }
```

because the `IEntityBase` is not implemented. Similarly, the follwing will also fail:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<int>
   {
        public object ID { get; set; }
   }
```

because this time `IObjectWithId<int>` is not satisfied. You may try to do this:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<int>
   {
        public object ID { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
   }
```

just to receive another compilation error for having 2 properties with the same signature.

The way to work this around, is to implement at least one of the conflicting signatures explicitly:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<int>
   {
        private object objID;
        private int intID;

        object IEntityBase.ID { get { return objID; } set { objID = value; } }     
        int IObjectWithId<int>.ID { get { return intID; } set { intID = value; } }
   }
```

Now, back to your code - you used `object` instead of `TId` which creates a rare but interesting case - the two `ID` properties **unify** because of their identical signature. So this class:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<object>
   {
        public object ID { get; set; }
   }
```

will compile, because the `ID` property satisfies both interfaces. However, the `EntityBase` class still has **two** `ID` properties in its method table (one coming form each interface). The two properties are automatically assigned to the same implementation in the `EntityBase` class by the compiler (the process is called **unification**).

The following code:

```
typeof(EntityBase).GetProperty(
    "ID", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

will look into the method table of the `EntityBase` class and will see two property entries for that signature and will not know which one to pick.

This is because you might have implemented your class like that:

```
   public class EntityBase : IEntityBase, IObjectWithId<object>
   {
        private object objID1;
        private int objID2;

        object IEntityBase.ID 
        { 
            get { return objID1; } 
            set { objID1 = value; } 
        }

        object IObjectWithId<object>.ID 
        {
            get { return objID2; } 
            set { objID2 = value; } 
        }
   }
```

See - the two properties can have **different implementations**, and at that point the runtime cannot know whether their implementations are unified (reflection happens at **runtime** now, not at compile time when unification was performed). The `AmbiguousMatchException` you received is the .NET framework's way to prevent you from executing code with possibly unknown/unintended behavior.

When no different implementation is provided for each interface (as in your case), the only implementation you have is called by both entries in the method table for that signature, but still there are **two entries** pointing to the same property. To prevent the framework from confusion, you should use a type *high enough* in the inheritance hierarchy, so that it has only one entry in its method table for the member you want to reflect. In our example, if we use the **interface** types instead when reflecting the `Id` property, we will solve our case, as each of the interfaces has only one entry in its method table for the requested signature.

You can then use

```
Console.WriteLine(
    typeof(IEntityBase).GetProperty(
        "Id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(
    typeof(BusinessObject<object>).GetProperty(
        "Id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
```

depending which implementation you want to retrieve. In case of my latest example, where each interface has different implementation, you have the ability to invoke reflective any of the implementations, by choosing the correct interface. In the example from your question, you may use whichever interface you want, as both have one implementation.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not understand it. If EntityBase inherits two Id properties, but the compiler lets them unite into one - EntityBase.Id, then this should be period, i.e. EntityBase has one Id property. And it should have been returned by the reflection. Anyway, I have to check it on .NET 4, because it seems a bug of .NET 3.5 installation on my machine.

Comment: I have edited my post with further explanation. Difference in the different framework may come from the way reflection works. There is a binding flag that would enable you to search either the given type's properties, or also the inherited properties. In the second case, you will run into the ambiguous match exception. At least, this is how I think different people get different results for the same code - because the different framework versions use different flags internally. If that's the case, it may be considered a bug in the framework.

Comment: OK, now I understand. Is there a way to examine the internal structure of a type? Using some kind of an external tool?

Comment: Yes, you might get enough info for public members by examining the Object Browser in Visual Studio. You can see there the base types of a class and also toggle the visibility of inherited members. However, if you need a look into the private fields of an object, a tool similar to Red Gate's reflector might be useful. Unfortunately, it has become a paid tool. What you need to do related to your case is if a member with the same signature comes from more than one interface and/or a base class of a type. Keep in mind though that by definition return type is not part of the signature.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when there were two implementations for an one interface method.