# Assembly Load fails when i load my assembly using reflection

Tags: c#

Hello i'm having difficulty loading an assembly using reflection. Sometimes when someone do a small program and use assembly Load many antiviruses show you false/positives.
For example in this code:

```
//Load the bytes as an assembly
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer);

//Execute the assembly
object[] parameters = new object[1];                
exeAssembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

So i was trying using only reflection like this:

```
typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load").Invoke(null,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
```

However, i dont know the reason but this throws me an exception, returning me the follow error:

```
typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load").Invoke(null,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
    Problem signature:
      Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
      Problem Signature 01: Proof.exe
      Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
      Problem Signature 03: 591f941f
      Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
      Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1590.0
      Problem Signature 06: 5787ed44
      Problem Signature 07: 1037
      Problem Signature 08: 60
      Problem Signature 09: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatch
      OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
      Locale ID:    3082
      Additional Information 1: 0a9e
      Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
      Additional Information 3: 0a9e
      Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

    Read our privacy statement online:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

    If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
      C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

My question is how i can use reflection to avoid false/positives when i use assembly load.. At the moment i checked but all seems useless.

Comment: Check this answer to know about ambiguous match error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745853/can-anyone-explain-to-me-why-the-following-code-throws-system-reflection-ambiguo

Answer (score 0):

I think as per error.

> Problem Signature 09: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatch

So in Assembly.Load there are multiple overload. So when you pass object[]{decryptedBuffer} it get confuse that which one to use. Like String overload or Byte[] Overload.

Use following way solve your problem.

```
typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load", new Type[] { typeof(byte[])}).Invoke(null,new object[] {decryptedBuffer});
```

Comment: Does you decryptedbuffer contains proper byte array of assembly ? What does it contains ?

Comment: Like i said in the first method works fine and contain my assembly like any dll or binary but when i use the code you put never load my assembly, check with the first method i put in the post and your method , at least for me your code didnt work.

Comment: You said this works Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(decryptedBuffer) and I assumed that decryptedBuffer is byte[] array. Now in order to work with typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load") you have to make modification with typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("Load" , new Type[]{ typeof(byte[] }) so it will get proper overload of Load method.

Comment: look the post i use exeassembly and entry point to invoke my console/assembly will not work in my example.